# moment convert json object into date in javascript

Tags: angular, momentjs

i want to convert JSON object into date with moment

i tried following code...but didn't work:

```
let val = {'year':2019, 'month': 06, 'day':25};
const dob = moment(JSON.stringify(val), 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

and my expected result is: 
'2019-06-25'

any suggestions?

Comment: For month, is it 0-based or 1-based? If we were to do it in Vanilla JavaScript (not moment), it is 0 based

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.format()` method to convert it into the desired format.

```js
let d = moment({'year':2019, 'month': (06 - 1), 'day':25}).format("DD-MM-YYYY")

console.log(d);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: +1 and it would be nice to add the document reference to the answer as well. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/object/

Answer (score 0):

You expect this:

```
{"year":2019,"month":06,"day":25}
```

In order to use this format

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

But JSON.stringify output this because number are integers:

```
{"year":2019,"month":6,"day":25}
```

Then you should:

```
moment(JSON.stringify(val), 'YYYY-M-D');
```

Comment: moment doesn't have method to covert JSON object to date..?